# How to delete history of deleted commit?

Tags: github

I would like to find a way to remove commit history remaining in github.

I've fork a repository to do some work. I forgot to set config of name and email.

Therefore, for the first commit, it is pushed with incorrect credential.

I fix it by rebase, and the commit is deleted. I push again, so I cannot see that pushed in the git log.

However, the history of the first pushed is still shown in the github. This is because I refer to the issue number of the forked repository.

Is there a way to remove that history from github?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for how you could clean your history from this [link](https://gist.github.com/stephenhardy/5470814):

```
-- Remove the history from 
rm -rf .git

-- recreate the repos from the current content only
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

-- push to the github remote repos ensuring you overwrite history
git remote add origin git@github.com:<YOUR ACCOUNT>/<YOUR REPOS>.git
git push -u --force origin master
```